# React Styled Components selector for self AND children?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I would like to apply a CSS style to my styled-component element as well as all its children, is there a way to do this with a single selector block? Below is what I have now, I want to accomplish the same thing without duplicating the text `transition: 0.5s ease`

```
const ImagePreviewWrapper = styled.div`
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  & * {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, this worked for me:

```js
const ImagePreviewWrapper = styled.div`
  &,
  * {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
  }
```